# Good book/article that goes into depth about transversality conditions?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, dynamic-optimization

I know how to derive the transversality condition in simple models like the Ramsey model.

However, I am looking to develop a deeper understanding of transversality conditions in more complex models. However most macroeconomics books I've seen only have about 1 page about the transversality condition, namely its simplest form.

**Is there a good book that shows how to deal with more complex trannversality conditions than the one in the ramsey model?** e.g. if the utility function contains a term for assets?

Comment: @HerrK. No those questions are all very simple for me. As an **example** of what I'm talking about is the following (mind you I'm not looking for a specific answer to that example, but for a book that delves into the theory to understand things *like* that example). Take the standard Ramsey model, but include capital in the instantaneous utility function. I.e. instead of $u(c_t)$ assume $u(c_t, k_t)$. If you solve this using the Euler Lagrange equations or Hamiltonian for a free endpoint problem, you will get a different (more complicated) transversality condition. Try it out if you want.

Comment: Again, that would be an **example** of what I'm talking about

Answer (score 3):

A textbook on dynamic optimization which treats transversality conditions at some length is [Chiang *Elements of Dynamic Optimization*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Dynamic-Optimization-Alpha-Chiang/dp/157766096X).  See especially sections 7.2 - 7.4 and 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

I think that references in this field can be of interest and useful also at distance of time from the original question.

Transversality conditions are a complex subject in calculus of variations and optimal control theory.

From a (mathematical) economics point of view, classical references are, of course, the books of Takayma, *Analitycal Methods in Economics*, and *Mathematical* *Economics*, where optimal control and calculus of variations are exposed in detail, of course with applications to economics.

If you want a deeper insight from a mathematical point of view, there are a lot of books in calculus of variations and optimal control theory.

A classical reference in calculus of variations is Gelfand and Fomin, *Calculus of Variations*, Dover Publications Inc., 1991.
A good introduction to optimal control theory is Macki-Strauss, *Introduction* *to Optimal Control Theory*, Springer-Verlag, 1982.

For optimal control theory, if you have the curiosity of seeing original sources, there is the original text by Pontryagin, L.S. Pontryagin, V.G. Boltayanskii, R.V. Gamkrelidze, E.F. Mishchenko, *The mathematical Theory of* *Optimal Processes*, Wiley (1962), where the 'Pontryagin's Principles of Maximum 'are stated.

Actually, the 'Principle of Maximum', is not a single theorem, but a collection of theorems, and the question of transversality conditions is analyzed in each case.

But I warn you: the proof of the **first** Maximum Theorem in Pontryagin's book is about forty (40) pages!

That's to say that it is not a simple subject.